# Cannot add aspx file to root folder

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

Using the Object Model and I'm trying to add a file to the root folder of a document library.  The file is an aspx page which links to a file handler control we have.  The problem I am running into is that if the action is triggered by someone with only Content permission I get an exception.

If the user is a Site Collection admin then the upload works fine.

- ULS shows an Access Denied error.
- We do not have aspx files on the denied list.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Provisioning files to the root folder is not exactly a well-documented or best practice.  I would suggest putting the page in a document library instead unless you have a good justification for putting it in the root folder.

As an aside, non-admins cannot even *see* documents in that folder in SharePoint Designer, so I suspect you will not be able to get around the SCA requirement to upload to that folder.

Comment: Although I should add that I've done that lots of times in sandbox solutions...it prevents users from being able to edit the files.  But if that's the reasoning you are using it doesn't stand to reason that regular users would be able to upload to it.

Comment: I agree with Derek, create a document library and upload the .aspx file to that library. You then have two options: Either grant users Add rights to that library, or wrap that section of code in elevated permissions code, and make the library read-only.

Comment: Sorry guys.  I forgot to include that I am actually going spList.RootFolder.Add() where spList is a document library.